# How to get shared secret with BouncyCastle given two keys?

Tags: c#, bouncycastle

Need shared secret between a given 64 byte public key (theirs) and a 32 byte private key (ours).

I have the keys which get produced by an outside provider (P-256 ECC code). The public keys are 64 bytes and the private keys are 32 bytes.

I cannot figure out how to get BouncyCastle to import these keys. It seems to expect DER encoded keys, but that is not what I have to work with.

```
public static byte[] GetSharedSecret(byte[] their_public, byte[] our_private)
{
  // their_public: 64 byte public key
  // our_private: 32 byte private key
  var pri = PrivateKeyFactory.CreateKey(our_private); // this fails
  var pub = PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey(their_public); // this fails

  // Expected to produce a 32 byte shared secret:
  return ??SomeBouncyCastleCode??.GetSharedSecret();
}
```

My expectation is that encryption/key code works with 32 and 64 byte arrays for keys. When working with embedded devices and other areas where code space is limited, there is no luxury to be able to deal with wrapped/DER/xyz encoded keys. These are stripped down to the actual key values and that is all I have to work with.

I cannot figure out how to get this to work with BouncyCastle.

Comment: Your keys, being byte arrays, are thus encoded forms of actual ECC parameters. We can only guess on what that encoding is. My guess would be: the public key is the encoding of two 32 byte big endian integers representing the (x,y) coordinate of the point, and the private key is another big endian integer.

Comment: @JamesKPolk - I don't know if this helps, but if I manually encode the key using BCRYPT_ECDH_PUBLIC_P256_MAGIC = 0x314B4345, I am able to import into Microsoft's cryptopgraphy as a valid (and usable) CngKey (CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob). Although, this doesn't solve my problem because I need the Bouncy Castle solution that is portable.

Answer (score 1):

`AgreementUtilities.GetBasicAgreement` returns `IBasicAgreement`, which you can `Init` a private key and `CalculateAgreement` with a public key. The calculation result is a `BigInteger`.

For parsing the keys, you can use `Curve.DecodePoint`.

Here's an example:

```
var ecP = ECNamedCurveTable.GetByName("curveNameHere");
var ecSpec = new ECDomainParameters(ecP.Curve, ecP.G, ecP.N, ecP.H, ecP.GetSeed());
var publicKey = new ECPublicKeyParameters(ecSpec.Curve.DecodePoint(YourByteArray), ecSpec);

IBasicAgreement agreement = AgreementUtilities.GetBasicAgreement("nameHere");
agreement.Init(privateKey);
BigInteger result = agreement.CalculateAgreement(publicKey);
return result.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it assumes that `privateKey` is a CipherParameters object, but OPs private key is just 32 bytes. So this won't work for him.

Comment: @SGKoishi An exhaustive search of the BouncyCastle namespaces does not yield any methods/classes named ECNamedCurveTable nor the others you have listed. I can't find these anywhere (with the exception of AgreementUtilities - this I can access). I am using the NuGet package Portable.BouncyCastle-Signed which we need to target mobile devices and other IoT devices.

Comment: @ts90 You're right. I'm using the default version of BouncyCastle, which has `Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X9.ECNamedCurveTable` ([src](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/master/crypto/src/asn1/x9/ECNamedCurveTable.cs)) and other methods. You may find some useful code from this version, but I'm not sure if there's a better way to do that.